# Doxygen for *.ino-files (Arduino)

Tags: arduino, doxygen

I would like to use Doxygen for documenting my Arduino code. For this I need the *.ino-files in my project to be treated like *.c-files and be parsed with the C code parser in Doxygen. I think there was a setting somwhere for this mapping but I can't find it anymore.

My settings so far:

```
FILE_PATTERNS          = [...] *.ino
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Oh, I think I already found the option. It is located under "Project" in doxywizard, "EXTENSION_MAPPING". These are the options that seem to be working for me now:

```
FILE_PATTERNS = [...] *.ino
EXTENSION_MAPPING = ino=c
```

And the tag that gets me every time: A @file-tag has to be added to the top of the file, otherwise it is ignored by Doxygen. Like so:

```
/**@file sketch_1.ino */
```

Comment: Actually, it's enough for the @file-tag to look like this (i.e. without filename):

    /**@file*/